# How to avoid page appearing in "Back" button history

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have a little project with one static html-page and two dynamic ones, which are produced by server-side python scripts.

Workflow is straightforward: input -> wait -> ready.

All works, but in "Back" button's history "wait" page is stored too. So if user (on "ready" page) press "Back" button once, he goes to "wait" page. I don't want to disable back button, I want one pressing "back" button transfer user to "input" page.

Is there any method to delete "wait" page from back button history? Or, maybe, this task can be solved in other way?

Thank you for a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
       if(window.history.forward(1) != null)
           window.history.forward(1);
</script>
```

Comment: if I understand correct, this code will redirect user from intermediate page to desired (BTW, it seems to be `window.history.back()`), and I can use this approach too. But my goal is don't add intermediate page to history menu.